# Java 2D graphics line drawing in Windows 7

Tags: java, swing

Am using jdk1.6 updates 24.

Am facing the issue regarding line drawing in windows 7.  In my project I've three components in panel. For example three panels,line starts from middle of one panel and ends with its border and the second panel starts line drawing from the end coordinates of that line and finishes in that panel end. The third panel starts with the coordinates from this finishing point.

So in view the entire structure would as a continuous (not necessary as straight) line.
In Windows XP its working fine and no issues but windows 7 the coordinates mismatches so the line breaks up from its continuity (i.e the coordinates from one panel ends does not match the coordinates of next panel line starts).

Am confused whether its issue operating system or API or any issue with coding standards. This issue occurs with platform dependent but am using swing components with overridden renderer. How to solve the issue?

Am in doubt with renderer make platform dependent which has been overridden for project specific. How to write platform independent renderer?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you include some code in the question to make the question more clear?

Comment: @Alpine I 'vote down' "..some code" and 'vote up' SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Many newbies do not know where the code is broken, and post the wrong code snippets.

Comment: @Andrew I agree, but without looking at the code it is difficult to answer this question.

Comment: You might take pictures, too. This sounds like a [L&F](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) disparity for insets/borders. What layout?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can create some sort of "global coordinate system" using the size and position of the JPanels. Take a look at this part of the JComponent doc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getX%28%29. With that, you should be able to find the positions and sizes of the panels relative to eachother. The code from your paint() function would help too.